# What does "bite" here mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Olivetti’s whisper was cold. “You sure this time?” Langdon didn’t **bite**. “We need a map. One that shows all the churches in Rome.”
>
> —Angels & Demons

Bite has a meaning of *taking the bait* fish-wise but I don't see it fit in here. It just seems it mean Langdon just hold his tongue and turn the attention to other stuff in this context. What does it mean actually?

Comment: What is the context? We need more context, but reading the line it seems **bite** means **to accept a suggestion or an offer**

Comment: The context is basically Landgon got the wrong place in the first try and they failed to catch the killer and now Olivetti(the operation commander) was making sure Langdon was not wrong again.

Comment: I think Olivetti's "You sure this time?" is a bait. If he had answered this probably a trick question, he would've been tricked, i.e. taken the bait.

Comment: to accept, believe, etc. something, especially when someone tries hard to persuade you to accept or believe it. e.g. They tried to sell us a fake Picasso, but we didn’t bite. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bite_1  Damkerng T. is right.

Comment: Here is the [rest of the page for reference](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=KOSmsuNbDJ4C&pg=PA324&dq=%22Olivetti%27s+whisper+was+cold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yz65U8auM8WNkwWM_IG4AQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Olivetti's%20whisper%20was%20cold%22&f=false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Olivetti's tone was mocking and he was trying to provoke a reaction, then *bite* meaning *taking the bait* would make sense. I haven't read the book, so I couldn't say if that was the case. Otherwise I would just assume it was bad writing. Dan Brown is a [notoriously clumsy writer](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000844.html). As a learner of English, you probably shouldn't be reading him ;-)

Comment: I second whatever you mentioned about the author and his writing style.

Comment: You may not *like* Dan Brown's prose style, but his command of English is vastly superior to almost all people who might ever need to ask a question on ELL (and most answerers). A lot of native speakers find it highly "readable", which is why he's sold so many books. The idea that reading his stuff might hinder non-native speakers in their attempts to become fluent in English is nothing more than misplaced intellectual snobbery. No different to pouring scorn on Harold Robbins or Jeffrey Archer just because they're not writing "high literature". Certainly ***bite*** here is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, who said anything about high literature? I do think that language learners should consume fun pop culture content. I do that myself. I watch a lot Japanese anime dubbed into French. It's not exactly high brow stuff. Did you read the page I linked to? What do you make of things like "the curator froze, turning his head slowly"? That's kind of confusing, don't you think? Do you have a better explanation for what "Langdon didn’t bite" meant? Did you notice the winking emoticon at the end of what I wrote? What do you suppose that meant?

Comment: I did read your link. As a graduate in Literary Studies, I have to say the writer there didn't seem to know what he was talking about. And although *you* may (for all I know) have the credentials to nitpick over Brown's style, I know for a fact that @Man_From_India hasn't. If he could write as well as Brown, he certainly wouldn't be asking questions here.

Comment: On the specifics, it's not at all unreasonable to *freeze* (one's entire body, which might previously have been, for example, walking hurriedly) at the same time as *slowly turning one's head*. And the idiomatic use of ***bite*** here is pretty unambiguous even with just what I can see. Langdon didn't allow himself to be provoked into defending himself from the implication that since he's obviously been wrong on some earlier point, he might also be wrong *this* time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you can't freeze while turning your head. That's just silly. "The mountainous silhouette of his attacker stared through the iron bars". That's absurd. How could you learn English from that? If you didn't know the word _silhouette_ and you tried to guess its meaning from the context, you would have no chance. I did suggest Olivetti might have been trying to provoke a reaction, to make Langdon bite. Did you not read that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I will grant that you could freeze your body while turning your head, but he didn't say that, and the reader would have to struggle momentarily at least to come up with such an image.

Comment: I don't have to struggle (even momentarily) to understand his relatively fluid style. Would you say learners shouldn't engage in and study *spoken discourse* simply because it contains a large number of "errors" that wouldn't be expected in formal written texts?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, no, of course not, don't be silly. I said I watch anime, which 100% spoken discourse. Anyway, the site is complaining that there are too many comments and that we should take this to chat, which I don't want to do because I have to go. Bye, and have a great day!

Comment: @Fumble - I think Dangph's remark here was meant to be tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @J.R.: That's as may be, but he posted a link to a pretentious diatribe which was *not* "tichy", and the overt substance of the negative evaluation had been endorsed by what I consider to be at best an ill-informed comment. But what do I know? I've never even *heard* of the "possible alternative sense" in your answer *(bite = believe a lie)* - maybe for people who do know that meaning there actually *is* a possibility of ambiguity in OP's cited usage. Not for me though.

Comment: @Fumble - I suppose "bite" – when used figuratively – could be used to mean "get enticed into performing some action that will be regretted later." In other words, "he wouldn't bite" could be used just about interchangeably with "he wouldn't take the bait." That's hard to confirm, though; a Google search for `he wouldn't bite` returns results about [recent football matches](http://www.londonsmilecare.co.uk/another-solution-to-suarez-biting-habit/) and stray dogs :^)

Comment: @J.R.: On reflection, it is a rather odd usage. I've always assumed it derives from *rise to the bait*, but for me at least it usually occurs as something like *"Go on, then. I'll bite"* meaning *"I'll respond to your apparently trivial/mistaken argument"* - but there's often a sense of *"I'll bite **back**"* (at the implied criticism in your argument).

Comment: get a room, guys

Comment: The irony of this phrase in what's supposed to be a linguistic critique: "neither Barbara nor I are able to claim".

Answer (score 4):

With so little context, it's hard to say exactly what the phrase means in this specific situation, but I think you have the right idea.

“You sure this time?” sounds like a **taunt**. Someone that *bites* on a taunt gets irked, or gets sidetracked into an argument. Someone that doesn't "bite" keeps his original train of thought, and focuses on the matter at hand.

The phrase could also be used when alluding to a **lie**. If Evan broke a window, but then pointed at his little brother, saying, “I didn't break the window, Michael did!” Someone that *bites* on the lie might start upbraiding Michael, but someone who doesn't *bite* can see through the lie, and leaves the fault where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

> "You sure this time?” Langdon didn’t bite.

Olivetti is questioning Langdon's credibility, it sounds like Langdon was wrong about something before...  - he is asking if Langdon has made [another] mistake.

> Langdon didn’t bite.

Is exactly as you think, it's a sideways reference to him not '*taking the bait*', the bait being Olivetti's criticism - Olivetti is trying to get a reaction out of Langdon; Langdon simply ignores him and changes the subject: "*We need a map. One that shows all the churches in Rome.*”